# variable in class wont update after using the package keyboard

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using the package "keyboard" to create a console menu.

I want to check when confirm has been checked. However the problem is, if you click confirm, (self.current will equal the length of choices) self.current inside the definition run wont change,  when it has been changed by self.up or self.down.

Note: didn't include self.up or self.down because in self.run, self.current changes

```
class menu:
def __init__(self, maxChoices=1):
    self.maxChoices = maxChoices
    self.current = 0
    self.choices = ["Do something 1", "Do something 2", "Do something 3", "Do something 4", "Do something 5"]
    self.choiceSelected = []
    self.error = ""

def run(self):
    while True:
        self.show_menu(self.error)
        keyboard.add_hotkey('up', self.up)
        keyboard.add_hotkey('down', self.down)
        keyboard.wait("enter")
        keyboard.unhook_all_hotkeys()
        if self.current == len(self.choices) and len(self.choiceSelected) != 0:
            return self.choiceSelected
        elif self.current == len(self.choices):
            self.error = "\n" + bcolors.WARNING + "ERROR: Nothing selected!" + bcolors.ENDC
            str(self.current)
            input()

def show_menu(self, error=""):
    clearConsole()
    print(self.current)
    print("Choose an option:")
    print('┌' + '─' * max(len(s) + 4 for s in self.choices) + '┐')
    for choiceNum, choice in enumerate(self.choices):
        spaces = " " * (max(len(s) for s in self.choices) - len(self.choices[choiceNum]))
        if choiceNum == self.current:
            if choiceNum in self.choiceSelected:
                print(f'│{bcolors.BOLD + bcolors.OKGREEN}>>{self.choices[choiceNum]}<<{bcolors.ENDC}{spaces}│')
            else:
                print(f'│{bcolors.BOLD}>>{self.choices[choiceNum]}<<{bcolors.ENDC}{spaces}│')
        elif choiceNum in self.choiceSelected:
            print(f'│{bcolors.OKGREEN}  {self.choices[choiceNum]}{bcolors.ENDC}{spaces}  │')
        else:
            print(f'│  {self.choices[choiceNum]}{spaces}  │')
    spaces = " " * (max(len(s) for s in self.choices) - 7)
    if self.current == len(self.choices):
        print(f'│>>{bcolors.FAIL}CONFIRM{bcolors.ENDC}<<{spaces}│')
    else:
        print(f'│  {bcolors.OKBLUE}CONFIRM{bcolors.ENDC}{spaces}  │')
    print('└' + '─' * max(len(s) + 4 for s in self.choices) + '┘')
    print(error)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured out the answer....

I forgot to clear self.error so whenever enter was pressed afterwards self.error printed.

What threw me off was that when i tried to do an input, on terminal it would disappear so i couldn't check the real value of self.current